# Pullback of a smooth map along reduction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y \rightarrow X$ be a smooth morphism of schemes. Let $X_{red}$ be the reduction of $X$. I am interested in the pullback $Z = X_{red} \times_X Y$ and its relationship to $Y$. My questions are:

1. Is $Z$ reduced?
2. There is a canonical map $Z_{red} \rightarrow Y_{red}$ since reduction is functorial. Is this map an isomorphism (Is $Z_{red} \cong Y_{red}$)?

I want to understand questions like this as I would like to further understand the relationship between smooth maps and reduction maps. Formally smooth morphisms lift (non-uniquely) against reduction maps, and this would be a further property of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is true that $Z$ is reduced. The reason is that $Z\to X^\text{red}$ is smooth (since pullback of smooth is smooth) and then it's easy to see that $Z$ must be reduced (e.g. see [1, Proposition 2.4.4]--the Noetherianess isn't really needed).
2. This is also true. Namely, note that since $X^\text{red}\to X$ is a closed embedding and surjective so then also is the pullback $Z\to Y$. Since $Z$ is reduced this implies immediately that $Z=Y^\text{red}$.

[1] Fu, L., 2011. Etale cohomology theory (Vol. 13). World Scientific.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Yes, I did. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know if this works for flat maps instead of smooth maps?

Comment: @DeanYoung Have you thought about the case when $X=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$?

Comment: There's really no reason to suspect that $Z$ would be reduced, but $2$ seems more likely. When $X = \text{Spec}(k)$, $2$ is true as in sections $\mathcal{O}_Z$ we have taken the sections of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and modded out by the images of nilpotents. So $Z$ sits in between $Y$ and $Y_{red}$. That means that their reductions are the same. But I never had to use flatness, which is suspicious.

Comment: actually, I think I can show that if that diagram is a pullback then it is formally smooth.

Comment: Oh, I see; flatness is what makes modding out by nilpotents a valid sheaf, so that's where it was used.

Comment: if the map is an isomorphism, then the pullback is universal with reduced schemes as test diagrams, so it is universal in general (maps from $S$ to $T_{red}$ are in correspondence with maps $S_{red}$ to $T_{red}$). So 1 and 2 are equivalent.

Comment: In fact, that is an alternative way to see $1$ as well.

Comment: By the way, Alex- the reason I am interested in this is because it expresses what "continuously varying fibers" means. A fibration $Y \rightarrow X$ in topology is like a map $* \rightarrow X \mapsto  * \times_X Y$. A map of schemes $Y \rightarrow X$ induces a function $U \mapsto Y \times_X U$. The fibers are now pullbacks of maps into $X$ (maps from $U$ to $X$ are called $U$ points). (see next message)

Comment: For this "fibration" to really be a fibration, it must be continuous; it must send infinitesimally close points to infinitesimally close points.  It must send $U \sim V$ to $U \times_X Y \sim V \times_X Y$. And $\sim$ just means their reductions are isomorphic.